# JqGrid only-insert значение

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

День добрый!

А подскажите, может кто сталкивался. jqGrid, редактирование записей - формой.

Один из столбцов должен быть изменяемый только при добавлении записи, а при редактировании уже нет. Была идея сделать ему:

```
  editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:true}
```

Но оказалось, что readonly - это всегда readonly, даже если read там еще нечего.

Единственная пока идея - ловить beforeShowForm и отменять атриббут readonly на нужное поле... А есть более прямые способы?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сейчас тоже плотно работаю с данным плагином.

Что касается вашего вопроса - то только ручками ловить события beforeShowForm, так как для формирования форм Добавления используется один код, с небольшими различиями, и читают они одни и те же опции настройки полей

вот из доки

**Adding Row**

> The `editGridRow` method is also used to add data to the server, by
>   passing “new” as the `rowid`.  This method uses Common Editing
>   Properties from `colModel` and `editurl` option from **jqGrid**.

Comment: Честно говоря ожидаемо, но спросить стоило...

Нужно будет в саппорт кинуть идею. В принципе, не слишком красивая, но достаточно типичная ситуация, когда какая-то часть полей заполняется только один раз при внесении записи.

Comment: ну если есть желание сам перепиши код, добавь новые опции addoptions - и при создании формы читай их

Comment: да и кстати а приведи пример когда такое надо? что то интересно стало)

Comment: Любая задача, где допускается ручное внесение ключа уникальности.

В моем случае это усложняется репликацией данных)